# SXA watch CLI only minify and upload CSS only. JS and Scriban does not work

Tags: sxa

sxa watch All -d AND gulp, only track css. It says its watching js and scriban but when I save a js or scriban, CLI does not throw a response. Am I missing something ?

This is my config:

Sass (working)

```
sass: {
        root: 'sass/**/*.scss',
        components: {
            sassPath: 'sass/*.scss',
            stylePath: 'styles'
        },
        styles: {
            sassPath: [
                'sass/styles/common/*.scss',
                'sass/styles/add-highlight/*.scss',
                'sass/styles/background-colors/*.scss',
                'sass/styles/content-alignment/*.scss',
                'sass/styles/layout/*.scss',
                'sass/styles/spacing/*.scss'
            ],
            stylePath: 'styles',
            concatName: 'styles.css'
        },
```

JS (working), it was not working before but now its working as I did a sxa rebuild. after that now its working

```
     js: {
            path: 'scripts/**/*.js',
            esLintUploadOnError: true,
            minificationPath: ['scripts/**/*.js'],
            jsOptimiserFilePath: 'scripts/**/',
            jsOptimiserFileName: 'pre-optimized-min.js',
            es6Support: true,
            jsSourceMap: false,
            enableMinification: true,
            disableSourceUploading: true
        },
```

Scriban, Not working. ** issue is with scriban only.

```
scriban: {
        path: (function () {
            if (!global.rootPath) return;

            let rootCreativeExchangePath = global.rootPath.split('-\\media'),
                _path = './';
            if (rootCreativeExchangePath.length > 1) {
                _path = _path + path.relative('./', global.rootPath.split('-\\media')[0]).split(path.sep).join('/')
            }
            return _path + '/-/scriban/**/*.scriban';
        })(),
```

Scriban confiuration file:

```
{"siteId":"{F860FD06-F351-411F-B329-562D41B9941C}","database":"sc93_EXM.Master"}
```

This is the theme file structure:
[image]

Comment: Hey there, welcome, Love to help out but we're gonna need a lot more information, like what is your config set too? How are your files structured? have you used --debug and looked at the output? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi I have modified the question with config and file structure. I hope this is sufficient. Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Your config doesn't match your path for the scriban templates. You have:

```js
return _path + '/-/scriban/**/*.scriban';
```

if you look at your folder structure you don't have a folder named `-` before the scriban folder.

Change your path to this:

```js
return _path + '/scriban/**/*.scriban';
```

and it should pick up your files.

Comment: I did that as well. Still same thing. Does not work ....I tried adding a DASH folder and remove it as well. both way didnt work

Comment: issue was I had to remove first / from the path .... 
so correct method was return _path + '-/scriban/**/*.scriban';